# Converting the local coordinates to GPS (lat, long)

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, spherical-geometry

I am having the XYZ points in some local coordinate frame. Each point I have, can also be represented as the distance from the origin and the azimuth angle it makes with one of the horizontal axis.

I also have the GPS coordinates(lat,long) and the heading corresponding to the (0,0,0) point of the local coordinate frame.

I need to convert all the points in the lat,long.

The approach I can think of is to use the **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** formula from [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) link, as I have the:

- starting point(long,lat corresponding to the origin)
- distance between the origin and the actual point being converted to long,lat

But I am not sure what will be the *bearing* required in the formula. Does it relate to the azimuth, I have for each point?

Comment: What software are you using? Some software will allow you to create a CRS with your local origin. Are the points in metres from the origin? Can you give an example of some of the points you have?

Comment: Currently, I am looking to achieve this without any software. Yes the points are in metres from the origin. Apparently its the lidar data, below is the example of one such point  0.12 4.8 -7.6 50  (x y z intensity)

Comment: You can project to geographic coordinates with OGR if you're keen on writing your own package. You will need to define your own CRS with a vertical datum (ellipsoidal perhaps) and offset the standard false easting and northing with your known starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please elaborate more on this technique, as I am new to these type of conversions and standards.

Comment: It might be simpler to add the values to your known coordinate, but it will need to be UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator), what is your origin for the example point? Are the relative coordinates positive up, positive east, positive north? what programming language are you using? I know python, VB6, VBA, VB.net, C# and C++ (and others that aren't used any more) it would be more useful to frame an answer in a programming language that you understand.

Comment: The origin is in terms of GPS position(lat,long) is 43.0041, -78.7906, corresponding to the origin(0,0) of my local coordinate frame.  I am using c++, but python will also be fine.

Comment: I did a similar conversion - had cartesian coordinates in relative meters - however I rather decided to use UTM as I only had to get UTM coords for 0,0 point and then simply turn the relative distances (also in meters) to UTM. With lat/lon would be not so simple. Maybe first calculate UTM and then use some reprojection to WGS84 EPSG:4326.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python would be so slow at this, I would use C++. [Read your XYZ file using a normal ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once) then [use strtok to break apart the single line](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) into tokens and make the [string tokens into double](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/).

You will need to [find the local WGS UTM coordinate reference system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude) and [project your origin to this CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269752/gdal-c-re-project-coordinate-with-elevation-z) (sorry the OGR API is offline at the moment). From here you can obtain the local X,Y,Z of your origin, add your offset X,Y,Z, create an OGRPoint from the adjusted X,Y,Z, assign the local WGS84 UTM and then project to EPSG:4326 (WGS84/Geographic).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! Will certainly take this route.

Comment: I think I missed the minor detail regarding this conversion. As I mentioned, I have the long, lat corresponding to the origin of my local coordinate system. But the orientation of my coordinate system is not aligned with the GPS(the 0 degree of my local frame is not necessarily pointing North). So considering this information, what additional steps should I need to perform, before going ahead with the steps mentioned above. As far as I think, I will need to rotate each point by the angle my coordinate system makes with the North. Please share some info regarding this.

Comment: Your data does not look like bearing and distance rather an offset X and Y from an origin. What does your data look like when offset using the method outlined? Try a small section of a file in Python (quicker to write) and see if it aligns (within accuracy) with known to be accurate data.

Comment: Sure, I will try small section of my data, but my origin is not pointing to the North(0 degrees). So when I add UTM based offset to each point in my data, will it transform to correct UTM as I am not considering the orientation of my coordinate system.

Comment: The LiDAR data I work with is all projected and absolute, I find the data you have to be odd though I do understand that some drone data is reduced to a local datum to match other data. Your origin doesn't point *anywhere* it's a point and therefore has no orientation. Did you get metadata with your LAS data or can you contact the source of the data? I have assumed that this data is UTM, as that is the most common, reduced to a local datum but you're right it could be any projected coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, its correct that the data is not absolute and by **origin doesn't point to the North**, I mean that the Y axis is not pointing exactly to the North. So even after the transformation to UTM it will not be correct, I guess. And when you say _absolute_, I am assuming that your orientation is fixed. Lastly, the data I am using is from velodyne lidar.

Comment: Oh I see, it's vehicle mounted LiDAR, so the origin is moving. That makes it a bit more complex; without a timestamp I don't see you can do this. Is XYZ the only format that this system exports? If you can get ASPRS LAS it's possible to match the record to the origin SBET (smoothed best estimate of trajectory) which can be created from a string of GPS points (hopefully dGPS or your data will be rubbish) with X, Y, Z and time.

Comment: Yes, its mounted on top of vehicle and the origin is moving. But what if I can rotate my local coordinate frame- making it align with the GPS, so that it gets parallel with the Northing and Easting, **as I do have the GPS orientation** for my local frame. So once its aligned after applying the rotation, then I can add UTM offsets to all the points. And one more thing, I do have the timestamps  corresponding to each point.

Comment: But you don't have the timestamp for each point in your XYZI data to locate the origin between moving points.. there's no match between your csv and your vehicle.

Comment: I do have the timestamp for each point. And for the sake of simplicity, we can assume that the vehicle is not moving.

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption, not with LiDAR data, you must locate the origin point on the line between GPS points and take your orientation from the angle of preceeding to trailing GPS points **but** it's not just the angle of the vehicle from north, you must also adjust for tilt and yaw then compensate for the lever arm. When you purchased your scanner didn't you get software with it? It seems to me like you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: The software it provides is for visualizing the points in the local frame. For my application, it is safe to assume that vehicle is not moving, as my goal is quite different. And yes, regarding the angles, I am only considering the yaw(the angle of the vehicle from the north) and it need to be adjusted similarly for the pitch and roll. But overall if I make the rotation, I think then I can convert it to UTM. What do you think?

Comment: If that suits your purpose, take the angle to the next GPS point (or the previous to current) then get the vector from 0,0,0 to your data point and rotate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620745/c-rotating-a-vector-around-a-certain-point

Comment: Yes, That's what I think. Again, thanks a lot for this valuable discussion.